# Date time Picker bootstrap em modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, datetime, modal

É o seguinte o date time picker está a aparecer por traz do modal e não estou conseguindo colocar á frente tem como fazer isso?

Codigo que tentei:

```
.form_datetime {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999;
  }
```

e

```
$('input').datepicker({
          beforeShow:function(input){
              $(input).dialog("widget").css({
                  "position": "relative",
                  "z-index": 20
              });
          }
      });
```

Codigo do input:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="dtp_input1" class="col-md-2 control-label">Inicio</label>
   <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-12" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="yyyy MM dd - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="inserir_fim" id="inserir_fim" value="" required readonly>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></span>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
         </div>
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br/>
                                                    </div>
```

Date time picker que estou a usar: [Link do datetime picker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
O que está acontecendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como colocar o exemplo minimo, que seria um parte disso para analisarmos ...

Comment: Ja mudei é isso? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Qual é a versão do boostrap?

Comment: eu estou a usar o 4

Comment: No seu `JS` você está passando o `z-index` com 20, no `CSS` você pode usar o `!important` só pra ter certeza

Comment: Isso é igual o numero ele não sobrepõem na mesma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.form_datetime {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 999999;
  }

.modal{
     z-index: 99999;
}
```